# Write csv with all numeric columns as float with 3 decimal points

Tags: pandas

I have several columns of different types. I would like to format all the numeric columns into a csv as `.3` floats. So in this case, `a` and `b` should become `1.000` and `2.000` but `c` should stay `3` because its value is a string, not a number.

```
import io 
sio = io.StringIO() 
(pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1, 'b': 2.0, 'c': '3'}])
 .astype(float)
 .to_csv(sio, index=False, float_format='{:.2f}'))



TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when you use `astype(float)`, the third column is converted to float, if it is a valid number. Otherwise, `astype` will raise an exception. So you should probably change the types for each column separately. Second, the error is caused by an invalid format specifier. It should be "%.2f".

```
import io
sio = io.StringIO()
df = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1, 'b': 2.0, 'c': '1'}])
df[['a', 'b']] = df[['a', 'b']].astype(float)
df.to_csv(sio, index=False, float_format='%.3f')
```